# Fastboot recovery flash FAILED (Status read failed (Too many open files in system))

Tags: fastboot, boot

I'm trying to flash a magisk-patched boot image onto a device with an unlocked bootloader (but without a custom recovery).

I've patched the boot image without issue, but when I go to flash, this happens:

```
fastboot flash boot magisk_patched.img
Sending 'boot' (19648 KB)                          OKAY [  0.560s]
Writing 'boot'                                     FAILED (Status read failed (Too many open files in system))
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

Anyone have an idea what might be wrong?

Comment: try from windows 7 with latest [platform-tools](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads)